# wget -v -t=5 --no-clobber -x http://www.website.com/ What happen to this website when I run this command in terminal?

Tags: terminal, web-crawler

`wget -v -t=5 --no-clobber -x http://www.website.com/` What happen to this website when I run this command in terminal ?

Comment: [use something like this](https://gist.github.com/mikecrittenden/fe02c59fed1aeebd0a9697cf7e9f5c0c)

Comment: This is not a javascript question, what you are looking for is a `web crawler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using **Linux Terminal** you should get handy with the command `wget`!

***Syntax***
`wget https://www.example.com`

---

***Note:***

All the files will get downloaded from website to your **current dictionary**.

***Also:***

You can *download* a specific file from website by specifying it's (*exact*) location.

This becomes really handy will downloading some files , like `jquery-3.6.0.min.js` *(A file needed for independent working of jQuery)*

---

***Articles related / References :***

1. [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=wget)
2. [Reference Article](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)
3. [Difference between Curl vs Wget](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjz1oyyuLrwAhXYgf0HHRL0BbIQFjACegQIDxAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.howtogeek.com%2F281663%2Fhow-to-use-wget-the-ultimate-command-line-downloading-tool%2F&usg=AOvVaw0pDGEXi7_8ZoLAkssFPOXI)

Comment: This won't work. That will download the document at `http://example.com` and **only** that document with none of its dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing httrack and run following command

`httrack "http://www.all.net/" -O "/tmp/www.all.net" "+*.all.net/*" -v`